# Calculating mean and variance of total money spent

Tags: probability, statistics

This is a random sample of four homes representing the probability of the homes of having dust mite level greater than 2μg/g.

x:0,1,2,3,4

$P(x=0)=0.09, P(x=1)=0.30, p(x=2)=0.37, p(x=3)=0.20, p(x=4)=0.04$

If that dust mite level exceeds 2μg/g each home will spend $ 2000 for an allergen air purification system. Find the mean and variance of the total amount spend by the four sampled homes.

First what I did was that I calculated the mean of the distribution:

$0.09  \cdot  (0) + 0.30 \cdot (1) + 0.37 \cdot (2) + 0.20 \cdot (3) + 0.04 \cdot (4) = 1.8$.

Then I multiplied the mean with 2000$ to get the mean of the total amount.

For the variance I calculated variance = $E(x^2)- mean^2$ and I multiplied it by $2000$ to get the variance.

I'm having doubts about my logic, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure whether my understanding is correct, but if $T$ is a random variable representing the amount of money paid, then $T=0$ when $x=0,1,2$ and $T=2000$ when $x=3,4$.

That is $T$ is a sort of "scaled" Bernoulli random variable.

Hence the mean is $\mathbb{E}[T]=2000\cdot0.24=480$

and the variance is $\text{var}(T)=2000^2\cdot0.24\cdot0.76=729600$